# Turning a text "string" into a text "block" in Photoshop CS6?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text

If I select the Type tool, click somewhere in my composition and type in some text, it appears that I cannot resize the area the text occupies without resizing the text itself.

However, if I click and drag, to create a text block instead, I can use the corner handles of this block afterwards to reposition and resize this block, and have the text inside reflow automatically.

Is there a way to go from the first to the second? ie. first click, type in some text, then resize it as though it was a block?

Comment: The terms used in Photoshop are 'Point Text' and 'Paragraph Text'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Layer -> Type -> Convert to Paragraph Text

Comment: i have needed this for years i can't believe i only just googled it.  THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

In Photoshop CC 2015:

`Type` > `Convert to Paragraph Text`

and

`Type` > `Convert to Point Text`