# How can I convert Point Text to Paragraph and Vice Versa in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Turning a text “string” into a text “block” in Photoshop CS6?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8082/turning-a-text-string-into-a-text-block-in-photoshop-cs6)

Here we know that there are two texting modes in PSE - "single-line" and "paragraph".

The problem is how to convert point text to paragraph in photoshop?

Comment: Did Skaught's solution work for you? Please don't forget to mark questions as answered by accepting an answer if it was a valid solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a menu item to convert text.

[image: convert text]

If you have a layer containing point text highlighted in the Layers Panel, the menu item reads "Convert to Paragraph Text".

If you have a layer containing paragraph text highlighted in the Layers Panel, the menu item reads "Convert to Point Text".

Comment: Similarly, if you have the type layer selected, just right click on the canvas with the Type tool and the context menu will also list the option to convert it to point/paragraph text.