# convert to paragraph text in Photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6

I looked at this previous answer but when I select the text layer and find Convert to Paragraph text, it is grayed out. I am sure it is not already in paragraph text because it's just one long long string.

[How can I convert Point Text to Paragraph and Vice Versa in photoshop](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13649/how-can-i-convert-point-text-to-paragraph-and-vice-versa-in-photoshop)

Answer (score 2):

If the `Convert to Paragraph Text` option is **greyed out** it can only mean the highlighted layer in the **Layers Panel** is **not** a *live* text layer.

If a text layer *is* highlighted in the Layers Panel, the menu will read either `Convert to Paragraph Text` or `Convert to Point Text`.

If going to the type menu above doesn't work, try "right clicking" on the actual text layer in your layer panel box and select convert to paragraph text.

Comment: I can't even begin to tell you the amount of frustration I've experienced over this. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy to differentiate between the two. Basically, paragraph text, when being edited, shows an array of handlers all around the text box, to allow the transforming of the size of the box.

Also, if it's a paragraph text, your text will not be deformed during the box resizing, which is generally another big hint (with a string text you would have to do Cmd+T to transform).